# How to get id When Using Implicit Route Model Binding, i need it in unique validation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

// in the validation section "alias" field should be unique so i need this `NursingHome` object id(primary key) to force validation to not to check for this id.

I have checked it with `$nursinghome->getKey()` method but no success.

```
public function update(Request $request, NursingHome $nursinghome)
{
 $request->validate([
   'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
   'address' => 'nullable|string',
   'alias' => 'required|string|unique:nursing_home,'.$nursinghome->id,

]);

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['updated_by'] = Auth::guard('api')->id();
    $nursinghome->update($data);

    return response()->json($nursinghome, 200);
}
```

Comment: I cant understand what is your goal ?

Comment: i need id of this NursingHome $nursinghome object which is defined in function so that i can force validation rule to exclude this id when checking uniqueness of "alias" field

Comment: can u try like this, `'alias' => ['required|string|unique:tablename, nursing_home,'.$nursinghome->id],`

Comment: why $nursinghome->id returns null ? i need this id

Comment: no problem in the code. code is working fine without any error but the problem is that $nursinghome->id returns NULL.

Comment: @RadheShyamSharma, check the answer below.

Comment: ok no problem i will go with the alternate solution

Comment: You dont have an id, you only get an id when your data pass from model to database, when you are getting data from your view your request dont give you an id. `$table->increments('id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a know issue disscussed in [laravel github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18167), that if your model has two words like `NursingHome` the it is not injected in controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $nursinghome = NursingHome::find($id); //now you will get $nursinghome->id

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'address' => 'nullable|string',
            'alias' => 'required|string|unique:nursing_home,'.$nursinghome->id,
        ]);

        $data = $request->all();
        $data['updated_by'] = Auth::guard('api')->id();
        $nursinghome->update($data);

        return response()->json($nursinghome, 200);
    }
```

If your model having two or more words, you have to use only small letters.

Comment: Thanks for help but i already know this solution. i want to do this with Implicit Route  Model Binding. is it possible?

Comment: can you please tell me the advantages and disadvantages of this model naming convention ?